# How to remove floating tag?

Tags: html, css, image, jekyll, src

I am use Jekyll for make website.

I want add image to webpage but when I close `img` tag like this there is a floating `>` display on webpage under image:

```
<img class="img” {% asset image.jpg %} >
```

Why there is floating `>` ?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your closing quote on `img` is a fancy quote. Replace that with the same as the first one `"`

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag seems to have the wrong quotations and has no source.
Try this:

```
<img class="img" src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/img/my-image.jpg">
```

Comment: I'm going to guess because this question is just a typo issue and should be closed vs. having an answer that will benefit no future visitors. And OPs image works: _is a floating `>` display on webpage under image_ which means that the image is displaying and the source isn't the issue.